# Spring Boot Failed To Bind Properties Under .. To Int

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration, yaml

I'm trying to generate a random value for a port in my .yml file using `port: ${random.int(1024, 65535)}` on startup I am getting this error:

```
 Could not bind properties to 'SftpConfiguration' : prefix=recon.data.load.sftp.*, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'recon.data.load.sftp.port' to int
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:6
```

My config classes are as followed:

```
@Configuration
public class SftpSpringConfiguration {
  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "recon.data.load.sftp.*")
  public SftpConfiguration sftpFileRetrievalConfiguration() {
    return new SftpConfiguration();
  }

  @Bean
  public SftpFileRetrieval fileRetrieval() {
    return new SftpFileRetrieval(sftpFileRetrievalConfiguration()::createSession);
  }
}
```

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class SftpConfiguration {
  private String server;
  private String username;
  private Resource privateKey;
  private int port;
```

NOTE: Create Session is just standard boilerplate for setting up JSch client.

As you can see I leverage the spring configuration to bind the values into SftpConfiguration. The problem is on certain classes that I `@Autowired` my `SftpClient` in it tries to populate the fields with values from my properties. If I put something other then the `$random.int[1024, 65535]}` it works as expected, i.e. if I hardcode 1024 into the port property it works just fine. The goal here is to make it work with a random value for the port.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the syntax you are looking for is:

```
${random.int(1024,65535)}
```

Rather than:

```
$random.int[1024, 65535]}
```

Edit (adding example code):

src/main/application.yml

```
server.my.port: ${random.int(1024,65535)}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    @Value("${server.my.port}")
    private String port;

    @GetMapping("/port")
    public String port() {
        return port;
    }
}
```

Returns:
14745 (random port on every application startup)

Spring Boot Version: 2.7.5

Comment: I will test and let you know, but I'm fairly certain that way I got same error as well.